# JavaFX Invocation Target Exception - Illegal State Exception target not set

Tags: java, javafx, compiler-errors

My main class can't seem to find my fmxl file it seems but I'm pretty sure the pathing is correct. I don't understand what is happening.

Here is my main

```
public void start(Stage primaryStageObj) throws Exception{
        primaryStage = primaryStageObj;
       // System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/net/usikkert/kouchat/practice.fxml"));
        FXMLLoader loader2 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/net/usikkert/kouchat/practice.fxml"));
        Parent root2 = loader2.load();
        System.out.println("controller set");
        LoginController loginController = loader2.getController();
        loginController.setArgumentParser(argumentParser);
        loginController.setSettings(settings);
        loginController.setUncaughtExceptionLogger(uncaughtExceptionLogger);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Flake");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root2, 250,439  ));
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Perfect Version.png")));
        primaryStage.show();


        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent e) {
                Platform.exit();
                System.exit( 0);
            }
        });
        primaryStage.setTitle("Flake");
```

The error I am receiving is

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at net.usikkert.kouchat.Main.start(Main.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application net.usikkert.kouchat.Main
```

The error at Main.java:74 is my loader call `Parent root2 = loader2.load();`
I don't understand what the error is caused by is my fxml file not able to be found?

That is the path of my project
[image: This is the path of my project]

Comment: It means the FXML file cannot be found. (I assume if you uncomment the commented `System.out.println()`, it displays `null`?) The path looks correct, in that it corresponds to the correct file in the image of the *source* hierarchy you posted, so you need to make sure the FXML file is being deployed correctly. This means you need to make sure it appears in the correct place in the build or out folder, or in the jar file, depending on how you are building and running the project.

Comment: Yes it does display null. How do i make sure that it appears in the correct place in the build or out folder. I am building it as a executable jar

Comment: You need to check the contents of the jar file. E.g. `jar -t myfile.jar` from the command line/terminal (or your IDE should be able to show the content).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
 FXMLLoader loader2 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/net/usikkert/kouchat/practice.fxml"));
```

to

```
FXMLLoader loader2 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("practice.fxml"));
```